# In Gitlab api how to find out list of distinct commit ids and commit description between two branches?

Tags: gitlab-api

I have to find out the missed commits between master and a feature branch using gitlab ui rest services. What is the curl and syntax to get these details?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by using the Gitlab API

```
GET /projects/:id/repository/compare
```

More info at https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/repositories.html#compare-branches-tags-or-commits

By executing the following

```
curl -s --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <access_token>" "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/<project_id>/repository/compare?from=<branch_name_behind_in_commits>&to=<branch_name_ahead_in_commits>&straight=true" | jq '. | .commits[] | "\(.id) \(.message)"'
```

You will get the commit ids and their messages, that are present to `master_branch` and not to `feature_branch`

**Notes**:

1. `access_token`, you need to provide this to the command if your repo is not publicly available
2. `project_id`. this is the ID of the project to which you want to compare branches.

---

[image]

---

3. In the `from` field you should pass the branch that is behind in commits in comparison with the branch you specify in the `to` field